# SSIS Union All does not return all the records

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, union-all

Very beginner question please. I have a simple script that performs a lookup for records in a different table - in this case the doctor who was assigned for treatments of a patient. Due to the lack of data quality control, a number of records do not have the correct doctor id assigned therefore the lookup returns non-matching output. I then have to create a dummy doctor for those records. After that I would like to merge the 2 record-sets into 1.

In my test database, I have a total of 20 599 records. The lookup transformation returns with 9 124 records that provide no-matching output and 11 475 records that do. What I dont understand is when I do a Union All, the result only comes up with a total 17 885 records. (please see the screenshot below, problem occurs @ Find Servicing Doctor then Union All)

Never had this problem before. I use the same technique several times in other section of this script and they all return the correct number of records. Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image: Screenshot showing the number of records]

Comment: That's weird as hell. If you patch to SP1, possibly even to CU8, does the issue remain?

Comment: I am actually on SP1 (11.0.3128.0) Development Environment is on SQL Server 2012 Dev Edition (64 bit). Windows 7 X64 Build 7601 SP1

Comment: Highly unlikely, but if you put a row count transformation before the lookup, one on each of the lookup's output streams and one final after the union all, does the counts all match what the GUI is showing?

Comment: @theUnderdog - First check and see the Union all is correctly assigned with correct columnname. Second, Create a dataview before Union All and after Union all..

Comment: @ Billinkc The count transformations did match what the GUI showing

Comment: @ Maverick: I can confirm the Union All is assigned with the correct column name. Only 5 fields on each table and I checked several time to make sure there is no typo or anything like that. I did a dataview before and after the Union All but too many records are displayed, it is too time consuming to work out what is missing manually

Comment: Are the tables are in the same database? then it's just a matter or writing a SQL statement to find the missing rows. Even if they aren't you can use linked servers. Finding the missing rows might be the only way you can proceed on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue originates when changing the format of a field in the source or target. The Union all transformation does not automatically update the format of its output fields, which apparently causes some records that pass the transformation but that do not satisfy the format any longer to disappear. Deleting the Union all transformation, recreationg a new one and joining it with the other transformations solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without 2 paths from lookup.

1. You just set in first lookup window to 'Ignore failure'.
2. Add 'Derived Column' element and put something like this:

   ServicingDoctor-Replace'ServicingDoctor'-isnull(ServicingDoctor) ? "NA" : ServicingDoctor